# How to call one function library functions to another function library?

Tags: testing, vbscript, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I'm facing an issue where I want to use one function library function into another function library. I'm using HP UFT Tool.

**Funtion Library1:**

```
Function addition()
End Function
```

**Function Library 2:**

```
Function sub()
  Call addition()
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Both libraries have to be loaded using LoadFunctionLibrary or , both libraries have to be attached to the resources tab. Refer this [link](http://www.automationrepository.com/2011/09/associate-function-library-to-qtp-script/)

To execute your 'sub' function, there are other ways to call it, bu the easiest is call this in the driver script. It will automatically call the 'addition' function.

```
Call sub() '' in turn calls addition function
```

Comment: I've tried this but it is not executing the function like call sub()

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please disable error handling if any. Also, put some code like MsgBox "Inside Addition" in the addition function.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue. The error (unfortunately) referred to the wrong Function file (because UFT is so wonderful), but the error was a "Type mismatch: ''"

This happened because the Function in Library "A" was calling a Function in Library "B" but did not know about "B". I added a line LoadFunctionLibrary "B.qfl" above the call and the error was resolved.

Comment: This is a decent answer. Your other post is not. Please delete the other post. Also, you seem unaware that you can [edit] your posts. It is not needed to create a new one. As far as I know the system should have asked you "Do you really want to create another answer?".